# I want to use Jframe to display an image for 5 seconds

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe

I am making a game using JFrame. Before it starts, I want a picture to display for five seconds, then start the rest of the game. The game starts when the GUI constructor is called:

```
public GUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Razor Fin"); //initialize JFrame
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(1275,760);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(110,100)));

    frame.setVisible(true);
    try {dispLogo(frame);} catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

    jta = new JTextArea(30,90); //initializing the output field. The constructor takes in lines of text to set size, not pixel measurements.
    jta.setEditable(false);
    jta.setBackground(c);
    frame.add(new JScrollPane(jta));
    DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret)jta.getCaret();
    caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE); 
    frame.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(110,100)));

    jta2 = new JTextField();
    jta2.setBackground(c);
    jta2.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    jta2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,20)); 
    jta2.setHorizontalAlignment((int) JTextField.CENTER_ALIGNMENT); 
    frame.add(new JScrollPane(jta2));
    jta2.addActionListener(this); 
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

The GUI constructor calls dispLogo before creating the text boxes:

```
static void dispLogo(JFrame frame) throws InterruptedException
{
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("logo.png");
    JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(image); 
    frame.add(imageLabel);
    imageLabel.setVisible(true);
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
    imageLabel.setVisible(false);
}
```

Instead of displaying an image, it's just a black screen. Does anyone have any clue on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

A constructor should never create a JFrame, or make it visible. Here's a suggested sequence:

1. Your main() should create a runnable. Its run() method creates and a modal JDialog to display the initial image.
2. Then the run() method creates the rest of the GUI - a JPanel with the contents; add the panel to the JFrame, pack the frame and make it visible.
3. Pass the runnable to SwingUtilities.invokeLater().
4. You can create and start a SwingTimer that 5 seconds later dismisses the image dialog.

Comment: Alright, but how do I solve the problem without changing the entire program?

Comment: You mean, "How do I do it incorrectly and still have it work?" You don't. You have to change the entire program. As you have written it, it it totally the incorrect way to do it.